# Freeform - jquery lookup to fill in addresses?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, jquery

Looking for a plugin/script to autocomplete addresses in a form.

I've got a couple of Freeform forms that ask for name, address, and a bunch of other data.

And, I'd like it so that when a user starts typing in the address, it shows an auto-complete box underneath, and when you select, it fills in fields for city, state, etc.

I'm looking at [Geocomplete](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/), but this seems like a thing that others (probably lots of others) have already done, and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

I'm on Craft 2.9, and the regular version of Freeform (not pro).

Comment: You are free to change the freeform templates and include your required attributes with the js to make it work. I'm not sure what's the problem?

Comment: I'd rather use an off-the-shelf plugin, if it exists. Think this particular use case is something that would exist, and I could use and possibly even contribute to, rather than doing it from scratch.

Comment: Then you should use google and search for it. I doubt someone would create a plugin for this specific use case when you only need 5-10 lines of code in an existing plugin